# Displaying the user input using angularjs and ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to get date from the user and pass it to a service for other action but when I try to read the given input Im getting `undefined`, why is it happening and how to overcome 
html:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="getFromUser">
<ion-content>
From:
<input type="date" ng-model="start">
<br>
To:
<input type="date" ng-model="end">
<br>
<button ng-click="save()">GO</button>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("getFromUser",function($cope, userService){
$scope.save=function()
{
var userInput={'start':$scope.start, 'end':$scope.end};
console.log(userInput);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the typo on the first line of the Controller? $cope instead of $scope

Comment: It's working for me.. not sure what problem you have. Check is there any error?

Comment: @ikerVazquez I typed it manually here but in code it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried passing `ng-model` as parameter in function and I was able to read the given input. And this worked for me don't know what was the issue I had.

Html:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="getFromUser">
<ion-content>
From:
<input type="date" ng-model="start">
<br>
To:
<input type="date" ng-model="end">
<br>
<button ng-click="save(start,end)">GO</button>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("getFromUser",function($scope, userService){
$scope.save=function(start,end)
{
var userInput={'start':start, 'end':end};
console.log(userInput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller("getFromUser",function($scope, userService){
$scope.save=function()
{
var userInput={'start':$scope.start, 'end':$scope.end};
console.log(userInput);
}
```

Comment: Some comments explaining what the code fragment is doing would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work on browsers that support html5 type 'date', but it won't on Firefox for example. In that case you can use a 'text' or a datepicker instead.

(your code is missing an 's' on the parameters declaration on "$cope")

```
.controller("getFromUser", function($scope, userService) {
    $scope.save = function() {
      var userInput = {
        'start': $scope.start,
        'end': $scope.end
      };
      console.log(userInput);
    }
  });
```

You can see this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/tinchomm/pen/MJWrBv?editors=1111) works on chrome but not on mozilla.

And the $scope vars will take the date data once the date is valid.

Comment: I tried your code but the console log show `object:{'start':undefined , 'end':undefined}` . I tried for `type=text` and I get the same output as above mentioned.